Como llamar un clase de HTML a Javascript cuando en el documento de HTML hay varias con el mismo nombre?
Hola a toda la comunidad, estoy aprendiendo javascript y tengo un problema, ya que debo llamar dos clases del documento HTML por ejemplo:
<div class="displayName">Player 1</div>
<div class="displayName">Player 2</div>

para poder remplazarlas con el nombre del jugador que el usuario digite.
pero no se como puedo llamarlas a mi codigo de Javascript porque las dos tienen el mismo nombre de clase "displayName".
Aun no llego a ver for, o for each entonces la solucion que busco tendria que ser sin esas instrucciones
Alguna solucion que me puedan brindar les agradezco, se que puede ser muy facil pero estoy hasta ahora empezando a estudiar.

No son dos clases, es una única clase, y si la usas varias veces tendras que llamar a sus elementos como si de una matriz/array se tratara. Busca ejemplos de querySelectorAll y prueba, y si no te sale cambia la pregunta poniendo tu código problemático.

podes añadirle ID si es manual, de lo contrario si no Tenes forma de ingresar ID de forma manual, te recomiendo hacerlo como te respondió masterguru

Comenzar aclarando que tienes varios elementos con la misma clase, no con el mismo nombre.
Tal como están definidos ahora, puedes valerte del método querySelectorAll() para obtener un arreglo con todos los elementos que tengan la clase displayName. En este arreglo, los elementos aparecerán en el orden que están en el HTML, por lo que el elemento 0 correspondería a Player1 y el elemento 1 a Player2. Accedemos a los diferentes elementos de un arreglo por su índice usando corchetes, así: arreglo[indice].
Mira este ejemplo:


document.querySelectorAll(".displayName")[0].innerHTML = 'Ronaldo';
document.querySelectorAll(".displayName")[1].innerHTML = 'Messi';
<div class="displayName">Player 1</div>
<div class="displayName">Player 2</div>



En mi opinión, esta solución es demasiado frágil, pues el código depende de que se mantenga el orden de los elementos y que no se nos ocurra más adelante usar esa misma clase por otro lado.
Un mejor enfoque, si puedes cambiar el HTML, sería el de asignar ID's a cada elemento. Estos ID's tienen que ser únicos para toda la página y, en ese caso, podemos valernos del método getElementById() para acceder a un elemento específico. Esta solución es más robusta pues, mientras mantengamos los ID's (y regularmente lo hacemos) el código se mantendrá funcional.


document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = 'Ronaldo';
document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = 'Messi';
<div class="displayName" id="p1">Player 1</div>
<div class="displayName" id="p2">Player 2</div>




Lo que puedes hacer es asignar un id a cada div que sea como su identificador único:
<div class="displayName" id="player1">Player 1</div>
<div class="displayName" id="player2">Player 2</div>

Con esto lo llamarás desde tu JavaScript de esta manera:
document.getElementById("player1"); //para Player 1
document.getElementById("player2"); //para Player 2

Lo cual hace que sea más sencillo obtener el elemento en específico.
